# Analysing RSSI on Wi-Fi Networks

Tags: security, scapy, rssi, wifi

I am using scapy and a Wi-Fi card in monitor mode to extract data from probe requests and beacon frames travelling across a Wi-Fi network. Is it possible to use the RSSI to estimate distance of the device sending packets from the device I am using to pick them up? How does the value given in RSSI work - does it decrease over the life of the packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [RSSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication) is a measurement of the power present in a received radio signal.

It is not a protocol mechanism (like the [TTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live)).

Moreover, the value you will get is related to a physic variable (the radio signal power) which is not related to the distance. By example, a far radio station with a high radio power could have a stronger RSSI than a close radio station with a low radio power.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Seeing as RSSI is not suitable for what I'm looking for, is there any other way to estimate the distance of a device from an AP/device monitoring the packets?

Comment: @C1837 Nop there is none. You can still use the RSSI but keep in mind that is it not a *real* estimation of the distance (because of obstacles, source radio power, antenna direction, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RSSI to estimate position of the access point but you need to have more information, for example angle of arrival (AoA) or direction of arrival (DoA). In fact RSSI will be only additional information in that case :-)

To estimate the position you need to have good directional antenna (not omnidirectional), much time to do many measurements, good knowledge of math and physics, and patience. And the results will be still not so good :-)